# RoutedCommands Executed and PreviewExecuted events

Tags: wpf, routed-commands

My problem is that I would like to handle a commands in multiple places. For instance I have my custom UserControl where a Button is bound to some command. I have a command binding in that control but I also have a command binding in a Window which uses this control.

My aim is to perform some action inside the control while not interrupting handling of the command in the Window.

I tried experimenting with Executed and PreviewExecuted events but with no luck. Then I simulated the problem in a single window (code posted below).

```
<Window x:Class="CommandingEvents.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:CommandingEvents="clr-namespace:CommandingEvents" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="{x:Static CommandingEvents:Window1.Connect}"
        Executed="CommandBindingWindow_Executed"
        PreviewExecuted="CommandBindingWindow_PreviewExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding 
        Command="{x:Static CommandingEvents:Window1.Connect}"
        Executed="CommandBindingGrid_Executed"
        PreviewExecuted="CommandBindingGrid_PreviewExecuted" />
    </Grid.CommandBindings>
    <Button Command="{x:Static CommandingEvents:Window1.Connect}" 
            CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

```
namespace CommandingEvents
{
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Connect = new
            RoutedUICommand("Connect", "Connect", typeof(Window1));

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandBindingWindow_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CommandBindingWindow_Executed");
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        private void CommandBindingGrid_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CommandBindingGrid_Executed");
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        private void CommandBindingWindow_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CommandBindingWindow_PreviewExecuted");
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        private void CommandBindingGrid_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CommandBindingGrid_PreviewExecuted");
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit the button only "CommandBindingWindow_PreviewExecuted" is printed out. Why is that? I tried to set e.Handled to false but it doesn't make a difference. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea why that happens (and how it isn't a bug) but here is what was written in the [WPF wiki](http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q13.9.ashx):

> There is a particularity about
>   CommandBinding which is extremely
>   interesting and important to know.
>
> The CommandManager uses routed events
>   to notify the different CommandBinding
>   objects that a command execution was
>   invoked (through default gestures,
>   input bindings, explicitly, etc.).
>
> Up to now, this is fairly
>   straightforward. However, what is more
>   important is that CommandBinding will
>   mark the routed event from the
>   CommandManager as handled as soon as a
>   handler gets executed (either
>   PreviewExecuted or Executed).
>
> Finally, even if your handler has a
>   prototype that matches a delegate
>   called ExecutedRoutedEventHandler, the
>   Executed event from the CommandBinding
>   is not a RoutedEvent but a normal CLR
>   event. Setting or leaving the
>   e.Handled flag to false will change
>   nothing.
>
> Therefore, as soon as an Executed or
>   PreviewExecuted handler is invoked,
>   the RoutedCommand will halt its
>   routing.

Comment: Is there any way to force the `RoutedCommand` to continue routing?

Comment: @Matthew: Well.. You could always try to re-raise the event from the Executed method.

Comment: the link to WPF wiki is dead.  has that moved somewhere?

Comment: The edit queue for this post is full, but here's a wayback machine link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120103180929/http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q13.9.ashx