# Executed gets not called after PreviewExecuted

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

Here's my code:

```
var commandBinding = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommand.New);
commandBinding.PreviewExecuted += OnPreviewExecuted;
commandBinding.Executed += OnExecuted;
CommandBindings.Add(commandBinding);

void OnPreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = false;
}

void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
  DoSomething();
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.previewexecuted(v=vs.110).aspx) says:"...If the preview event is not handled, the Executed event is raised on command target."

This does work correctly for the PreviewCanExecute event. But in this case the Executed-Event will not get called when a PreviewExecuted-Event is listening.

I did not find anything around this topic so I want to ask, whether the behavior is intended or just incorrect.

Comment: Could be that code some other place got the event (through tunneling) and handled it.

Comment: Basically no. This behavior occurs even in a fresh minimalistic sample project with just a single button and the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it doesn't matter what you set `e.Handled` to.

Here is the code that decides which events to raise (ExecuteImpl in RoutedCommand.cs):

```
ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args = new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs(this, parameter);
args.RoutedEvent = CommandManager.PreviewExecutedEvent;

if (targetUIElement != null)
{
    targetUIElement.RaiseEvent(args, userInitiated);
}
else
{
    ...
}

if (!args.Handled)
{
    args.RoutedEvent = CommandManager.ExecutedEvent;
    if (targetUIElement != null)
    {
        targetUIElement.RaiseEvent(args, userInitiated);
    }
    ...
}
```

So indeed, if `e.Handled` is `false` after the preview event, the `Executed` event should be raised. But it is never false after a `PreviewExecuted` handler is invoked (CommandBindings.cs, OnExecuted):

```
PreviewExecuted(sender, e);
e.Handled = true;
```

It simply sets `e.Handled` to true after invoking the preview handler...

Why this is so, I have no idea. `PreviewCanExecute` works the same way, but it only sets `e.Handled` to true if `e.CanExecute` is set to true - if you do that in your preview handler, the `CanExecute` handler won't be called regardless of `e.Handled`.

My assumption is that "*If the preview event is not handled*" is an unfortunate wording of "*If the preview event **does not have a registered handler***".

Comment: You are cpmpletely right. Here (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandBinding.cs,213) is the reference. I will ask some microsoft employees for the "why"

Comment: See also [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4877259/3513925), which confirms that `e.Handled` has no effect and routing immediately stops as soon as the first handler (which will be `Preview*`) is executed.
@Stephan, any clarifications why?